# React - How can I get pagination to re-render based off amount of objects per view selected via user-input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a pagination that works with `<ToggleButtons>` ,users can select how many items they want to display per page. The problem is, when a user select's a different amount of items to display other than the default, the pagination display shows more than needed page numbers because the calculation of items to display doesn't get re-calculated into the `<Pagination>` function. So the interface is still displaying the default number of page numbers.

Please see this sandbox for more info:

https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-agnesi-29zq8?file=/src/App.js

Basically I have these buttons that display 2, 4, or 6 items. If you toggle any of the buttons you will see that the pagination UI does not re-render itself to calculate the correct number of pages. In return there are useless pages in the interface that do nothing. Please see for yourself in the link above.

How can I solve for this? I've tried adding another state but I still had the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that you need to make sure that you are updating the noOfPages when itemsPerPage changes . Take a look at this example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-smoke-dsxqo?file=/src/App.js

I have only made a few changes to your setup, but you can see that it should solve your problems. This function here is doing all of the heavy lifting.

```
  const handleItemsPerPage = (event, newAmount) => {
    if (newAmount === null) {
      setItemsPerPage(5);
      setNoOfPages(Math.ceil(SymbolData.length / 5));
      return null;
    }

    setItemsPerPage(newAmount);
    setNoOfPages(Math.ceil(SymbolData.length / newAmount));

    // Checking if the page number is too high given # per page.
    if (page > Math.ceil(SymbolData.length / newAmount)) {
      setPage(Math.ceil(SymbolData.length / newAmount));
    }
  };
```

For starters I added the null check before attempting to set state. Then I just updated the number of pages (setNoOfPages) to account for the new change in display number per page.

Finally I added one check that will help with your UX. If the user is viewing 2 results per page, then there are 5 pages. However, if they switch the number of results per page to 6, then there are only 2 pages, but the selected page is still 5. So I added a check to determine whether or not your app should update the current page to be within the range of total pages.

I realize that you didn't ask for that, but it was bugging me so I threw it in. Ideally you might even want to handle some of this with useEffect, but since that isn't part of your current code I didn't want to add complexity.

Comment: This is great thank you very much, there seems to be one slight error where the null does not seem to work. If a user toggles the same button they pressed, then the graphs will disappear.

Comment: Great point, @woof! My apologies, yes I forgot to add a return value to the null check. There are two ways to tackle that, by either adding a return inside of the null check (which you were doing initially!) or by adding the other actions to an else block. I have updated the sandbox with the latter solution, and this comment with the former. Both are good, though! I would also recommend exploring useEffect when you have time, as it will really help you with things like this. =)

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-calculate the number of pages when the items per page changes. You can do this with an effect, so import it and then add this inside your component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

...


useEffect(() => {
     setNoOfPages(Math.ceil(SymbolData.length / itemsPerPage));
}, [itemsPerPage]);
```

Of course `setNoOfPages` is the setter for the number of pages state, so gotta destructure that too when defining the state:

```
const [noOfPages, setNoOfPages] = React.useState(
    Math.ceil(SymbolData.length / itemsPerPage)
);
```

[I tweaked your sandbox to show this here](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-bose-g423t)

Comment: Thank you for the help, do you know if there is any performance benefit to use a useEffect here?

Comment: There's no performance benefit, but state and effect hooks are just a nice way to group logic and data together. If you set the `noOfPages` at the same time as the items per page, it can be a little messier cos there's one function multiple things. It has other advantages, e.g. if you wanted to set one but not the other, you couldn't reuse that handler function if you did both in that one function. It's just cleaner.